# How to implement Java configuration for both local and Jenkins execution?

Tags: java, jenkins, arguments

My Java (JAR Project) program needs to receive the following three parameters:

```
String workDir;
String sourceDir;
String outputDir;
```

How would you implement this knowing that this Java program must be runnable locally to test and must also be executable by Jenkins?

1. How would this run locally?
2. What's the Jenkins execution syntax?
3. How would Java class retrieve the argument value?
4. Do arguments containing directory paths need to be encoded?

Answer (score 0):

I have trouble understanding your question
is this jar already ready and you just want to call it from jenkins?
if so I don't see the problem.

basically Jenkins will use whatever java version you will instruct it to use, if no specific java was declared it will use the slave default java version so it will be the same as running it locally.

I hope it helped and if not please clarify the question